# For every ordinal $\alpha$, there is a cardinal number greater than $\alpha$ without AC

Tags: set-theory, cardinals, ordinals, well-orders

Let $\alpha \geq \omega$ be an ordinal number. Let $\operatorname{type}(A, R)$ be the only ordinal number $\beta \simeq (A, R)$. We define :

$$W = \{R \in  \mathcal{P}(\alpha \times \alpha) : R \text{ is a well order} \}$$

$$S = \{ \operatorname{type}(\alpha, R) : R \in W \}$$

Then, how to prove $\sup(S) = \bigcup S$ is a cardinal number greater than $\alpha$ ?

Comment: Can you first prove that $\sup(S) > \alpha$?

Comment: I could only prove that $sup(S) \geqq \alpha$.

Comment: And how did you do that?

Comment: Since $sup(S)$ is an ordinal number, if you could say $\alpha \in S$, then $\alpha \leqq sup(S).$

Comment: @AngolMois No, $\alpha \in \beta$ for two ordinals $\alpha, \beta$ is the same as $\alpha < \beta$, not $\alpha \leq \beta$.

Comment: The result that "for every set of ordinals, there is a strictly-greater-in-cardinality ordinal" is essentially the Burali-Forti paradox, by the way, if you want a term to look up.

Comment: @Patrick Stevens: Well, not essentially, since the Burati-Forti paradox doesn't require an instance of the axiom scheme of replacement.

Comment: @Angol Mois: As Arthur said, $\alpha \in S$ means $\alpha < S$. Now assume there is an injective map $f: S \rightarrow A$, where $A \subset \alpha$ is well-ordered by $R$. What is the order type of $(f(S),R \cap f(S)^2)$?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First note that $\in$ is a well ordering of $\alpha$, so it is in $W$; then assume towards contradiction that $\sup(S)$ is not a cardinal, this means that is equipotent to some smaller ordinal. Hit by definition all the ordinals below $\sup(S)$ are at most of size $\alpha$, and from here infer a contradiction.

Note, also, that the definition as you write it only works for infinite ordinals, which is fine since we can prove this fact by hand for finite ordinals. But you can modify the definitions so this theorem will be uniformly applicable to all ordinals.

Comment: $\forall \gamma \in \operatorname{sup}(S) (\vert \gamma \vert \le \vert \alpha \vert)$. How is that a contradiction to sup(S) being not cardinal?

Comment: If $\sup(S)$ is *not* a cardinal, then it has cardinality $\alpha$. But then $\sup(S)$ is an element of $S$. This is a contradiction, since $\alpha$ is infinite, so $\sup(S)+1$ also has cardinality $\alpha$ and is therefore in $S$.

Comment: What is $\alpha^+$? Why does it exist?

Comment: I think the key observation to prove the result is this $S = [|\alpha|, \alpha^+)$. Just could not understand why it was not mentioned in the answer.

Comment: Again. What is $\alpha^+$, and why does it exist?

Comment: I see, we can only say that $S$ is the set of all ordinals whose cardinality is $|\alpha|$ and then conclude by contradiction that it is a cardinal. Thank you!